# Api C# два похожих запроса работают по разному

Tags: c#, api, https

Есть два запроса

1. `https://localhost:5003/api/getTest`
2. `https://localhost:5003/api/get?path=C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\Connection.config`

```cs
[HttpGet("/api/getTest")]
public ActionResult GetTest()
{
   return Ok("Work");
}

[HttpGet("/api/get")]
public ActionResult Get(string path)
{
   var result = _xmlManager.DeserializeToObject<Connection>(path).Add;
   return Ok(result);
}
```

Запрос `getTest` возвращает просто `"Work"`
а, второй возвращает

```json
[
    {
        "key": "test1",
        "value": "Work"
    },
    {
        "key": "test2",
        "value": "Work"
    }
]
```

Так вот, суть проблемы:
После публикации в IIS первый запрос работает как и работал, но вот второй выдаёт ошибку

```
Страница недоступна
Сайт localhost пока не может обработать этот запрос.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

В Postman та же история.

Но если запустит API через IDE, всё работает.
Почему 2-ой запрос не работает через IIS?

Comment: А что IIS может зайти по такому пути `C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\Connection.config`? Может надо не абсолютный путь, а относительный?

Comment: Если такого файла нет (что скорее всего, нет доступа) то сервер упадет. А локально понятно что он есть

Comment: Да, на будущее. Чтоб недоумевать от подобного `Страница недоступна Сайт localhost пока не может обработать этот запрос. HTTP ERROR 500` люди давно придумали логгирование. Подключите логгер в свой проект и задействуйте его, для подробной записи входящих запросов, ошибок и проч.

Comment: @Bulson Логер конечно полезный инструмент, но здесь он мне не поможет. Я же писал что при запуске API через IDE тоже запрос в том же браузере выдаёт правельный результат. Значит по какой то причине через IIS не доходит запрос до метода get. И всё было бы куда проще если бы и первый метод давал бы такой же результат )

Comment: @AzizUmarov Файл 100% на место. IIS то тоже локально (localhost) же!

Comment: Тогда у IIS нет доступа. к Каталогу

Comment: https://www.kbpublisher.com/kb/setting-up-folder-permissions-in-internet-information-services-(iis)_392.html

Comment: @AzizUmarov Доступ есть. проверял

Comment: `Доступ есть. проверял` каким образом проверяли? От какой цчетки пул приложения запущен?

Comment: @tym32167 Пробовал и NetworkService и ApplicationPoolIdentity не сработало! Попробовал через LocalSystem всё заработало! Спасибо!

Comment: имхо проше дать права группе `IIS_IUSRS` на нужную вам папку и запустить пул от `asp.net pool identity` - так вы будете хотя бы более менее уверены, что никакие другие файлы ц вас не скачают.

Comment: @tym32167 На папку права `IIS_IUSRS` я дал, но это не сработало (. Да и по идее путь необязательно будет один, по идее путь от любой папки в которой будет нужный файл можно передать. По этому давать на каждую папку права тоже не вариант.